# Retrieving all records through multiple hasMany relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, relationship

Apologies for the vague title, I'm not quire sure if there's a name for this.

I basically have the following relationship between my models in my Laravel 4 application:

```
User -----< Template -----< Job
```

(users haveMany templates, templates haveMany jobs).

I want to retrieve all the jobs for a user (by their ID). Normally I'd do:

```
Job::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
```

But the link between jobs and users exists through the `templates` table, so I tried doing this:

```
$jobs = Auth::user()->templates->jobs;
```

But that gives me an error about the `$jobs` property not existing:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$jobs
```

How can I retrieve all the jobs for a user in this scenario? I'd prefer not making a relationship between `User` and `Job`, as it seems like I'm just duplicating the relationship that's already there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has a hasManyThrough relationship.  If User hasMany Template, and Template hasMany Job, you can setup a User hasMany Job through Template relationship.

User model:

```
public function jobs() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Job', 'Template');
}
```

With that relationship, you access the user's jobs via:

```
$jobs = Auth::user()->jobs;
```

With this, it is not duplicating a relationship that already exists; it is just setting up the syntax to use the existing relationships the way you need to.  You don't need to change any fields or modify any data.